# Extracting VCS Changes - Intellj Idea Plugin Development

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have a `VcsFullCommitDetails`, calling `.getChanges()` is returning empty array all the time. Appreciate any help or hint how I can resolve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at methods in `git4idea.history.GitHistoryUtils`

See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001208300-Get-a-list-of-commits-in-project

Comment: Indeed you are right, maybe just as a side mentioning, that to be able to access GitHistoryUtils you have to add as dependency `git4idea` plugin. Thank you Dmitriy!

Comment: it's `Git4Idea` actually